# ruby1.9.3 links to ruby1.9.1 in Debian Wheezy after install with aptitude

Tags: linux, debian, ruby, debian-wheezy, apt

I have just attempted to install ruby1.9.3 with `aptitude` but for some odd reason it keeps symlinking `/usr/bin/ruby1.9.3` to `/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1`.

Here are the ruby version in `/usr/bin`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   22 Mar  6 12:39 ruby -> /etc/alternatives/ruby
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6264 Dec  2 03:43 ruby1.8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6336 Dec  2 03:22 ruby1.9.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Dec  2 03:10 ruby1.9.3 -> ruby1.9.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5937 Dec 30  2011 ruby-switch
```

More links:

```
root:/etc/alternatives# ls -la ruby*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Mar  6 12:43 ruby -> /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Mar  6 12:43 ruby.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/ruby1.9.1.1.gz
```

And a little more:

```
root:/etc/alternatives# ruby1.9.1 --version
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
```

Obviously something has gone completely wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, that's normal. `ruby1.9.1` refers to the compatibility version, not the *actual* installed version. It just means 1.9.1 is upwards-compatible with 1.9.3 and you can call `ruby1.9.1` on that system just fine, even though it actually uses 1.9.3 in the background.

From the [package description](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/ruby1.9.1-full):

> This package installs the dependencies for Ruby compatibility version 1.9.1 (currently Ruby 1.9.3).